# Condition inside render method in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- i am new to react.
- i am facing a syntax error, can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below.
  am i missing any brackets inside if condition

> ```
> ./src/views/view.jsx
> Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/workspace//src/views/view.jsx: Unexpected token (129:41)
>   127 | 
>   128 | 
> > 129 |                                          if(this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId === null)
>       |                                          ^
>   130 |                                         {
>   131 |                                         <div>
>   132 |                                             <a className="closeButton" onclick={this.hidePopover}>Close</a>
> ```

```or-tag-here
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import SportsBody from '../../components/scores/tracker/score-tracker-ira';
import Player from '../../components/player/snapshot/player-snapshot-presenter-ira';
import {setSidebarAppMode} from 'sports-template-standard/lib/redux/layout/layout-actions';
import {updateMenu} from '../../redux/menu/menu-actions';
import {Overlay} from 'sports-modal';
import SportsDefect from 'sports-logger';
import {version} from '../../../package.json';



const sportsDefect = new SportsDefect();

class KickIra extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {popoverIsActive: true};

        this.launchGoalDetails = this.launchGoalDetails.bind(this);
        this.hidePopover = this.hidePopover.bind(this);
        this.sportsFollow = this.sportsFollow.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        sportsDefect.log('IRA Rollover Kick View Loaded  Ver:' + version);
    }

    launchGoalDetails() {
        this.props.dispatch(setSidebarAppMode(true));
        this.props.dispatch(updateMenu('score-details'));
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    **hidePopover() {
        console.log("insidePopup")
        debugger;
        this.setState({popoverIsActive: false});
    }**

    sportsFollow() {
        const urlToLaunch = `/inet/iraRollover/IraRollOver/InvRolloverLandingPage?fundId=${this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId}`;
        window.open(urlToLaunch, '_self');
    }

    getHeaderContent() {
        const {profile} = this.props;

        return (
            <span>
                <div className="title">WELCOME{profile && profile.firstName && `, ${profile.firstName}`}!</div>
                <div className="subTitle">Digital Investment Adviser</div>
            </span>
        );
    }

    static basketballContent() {
        return (
            <p>
                If you want to know more about the status of your IRA Rollover, use the link below
                to visit the IRA Rollover Tracker on our website.
            </p>       
        );
    }

    /*static basketballContentNoChange() {
        console.log("inside  basketballContentNoChange---->");
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }*/

    static popupFooter() {
        //debugger;
        /*return (
            <div>
                <a className="closeButton" href="javascript:;" onClick={this.hidePopover}>Close</a>
                <a className="iraRollover sports-modal-trigger" href="javascript:;" onClick={this.sportsFollow}>Check Out IRA Rollover Tracker</a> 
            </div>       
        );*/
    }

    /*static popupFooterClose() {
        return (
            <a className="closeButton" href="javascript:;" onClick={this.hidePopover}>Close</a>
        );
    }*/

    render() {

        //console.log("summary-ira this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId ---->" + this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId);
        //debugger;

        /*if(this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId === undefined || this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId === '' ) {

        }*/
        return (
            <span>
                <section className="gray-box snapshotContainer">
                    <div className="flex-container flex-2">
                        <div className="snapshot flex-item">
                            <Overlay
                                className="popover--IRA"
                                active={this.state.popoverIsActive}
                                headerTitle={this.getHeaderContent()}
                                enableCloseShortcuts={true}
                                maxWidth={800}
                                onClose={this.hidePopover}
                            >
                                <div className="dia-popover-content level1">
                                    <p>
                                        As you requested, we are in the process of rolling over the balance from your qualified plan to your new IRA.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="dia-popover-content level2 dia-text-center">
                                    <p>
                                        Feel free to take a look around your new dashboard; this is where we'll show you what's
                                        happening with your new investment player.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        There isn't much to display yet, so don't let that concern you.
                                    </p>




                                    {/*(this.props.playerInfo.functionDetailId !== null ||
                                 this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId !== '' ||
                                  this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId !== undefined ) && 
                                   SummaryIra.rolloverContent()*/


                                     if(this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId === null)
                                    {
                                    <div>
                                        <a className="closeButton" onclick={this.hidePopover}>Close</a>
                                        <a className="iraRollover usaa-modal-trigger" href="javascript:;" onClick={this.openIRATracker}>Check Out IRA Rollover Tracker</a> 
                                    </div>  
                                    }  
                                }


                                </div>
                                <div className="dia-popover-content level3">

                                    {
                                        this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId === null || this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId === '' || this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId === undefined ?
                                            KickIra.popupFooterClose() :
                                            KickIra.popupFooter()
                                    }

                                </div>
                            </Overlay>
                            <SportsBody />
                        </div>

                        <div className="snapshot flex-item">
                            <Player />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </span>
        );
    }
}

KickIra.propTypes = {
    playerInfo: React.PropTypes.object,
    scoreDetails: React.PropTypes.object,
    profile: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default connect(state => ({
    scoreDetails: state.scoreDetails,
    playerInfo: state.player,
    profile: state.template.profile
}))(KickIra);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `if-else` in JSX, if you want to put some condition then use either `ternary operator` or use `functions` (helpful when needs to check many conditions and it make code more readable).

Using ternary operator:

```
<div>{1==1 ? 'Hello World' : null}</div>
```

Using function:

```
<div>{this.checkCondition()}</div>

checkCondition(){

    if(1==1){
        return 'Hello World'
    }else{
        return null;
    }

}
```

Check the sample working code on `fiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/sgLywd6m/

Reference: http://reactjs.cn/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

Check this article on static methods in react class: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/02/02/static-members-in-es6.aspx

Comment: thanks for your reply...but if I am using ternary operator, I am facing this issue, can you help with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358231/onclick-function-not-working-for-anchor-tag?noredirect=1#comment71867709_42358231

Comment: created a sample code, and its working, it should working in your case also, btw which anchor is not working `close` or `checkout Ira....` ??

Comment: your code works in fiddle, i mentioned static will that be problem....this one is not working ----->            <a className="closeButton" href="javascript:;" onClick={this.hidePopover}>Close</a>

Comment: not working means what ??? r u getting any error or console is not printing anything,because i used same code on fiddle as well as in a sample project both are working properly.

Comment: its not calling this function hidePopover, so i am not able to close the pop up...i have put the contents of pop up inside static function, is it not working due to that

Comment: why you want to make it as static ?? remove the static word it will work properly, check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/se7vdwsp/  always use this keyword and avoid using static function.

Comment: even though I remove it still its not calling hidePopover, I dont see any error in console, any idea https://jsfiddle.net/uboe1c9h/

Comment: yeah i checked in console, its returning undefined, can you tell me how to fix it this.onclick
null
this.hidePopover
undefined

Comment: It's a huge code base that's the reason I pasted only few lines of code ...Is there any way to fix it :(

Comment: This is working: https://jsfiddle.net/bspq9cbd/1/
This isn't working: https://jsfiddle.net/uboe1c9h/  ------> updated code below  {
                                        this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId === null || this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId === '' || this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId === undefined ?
                                            null :
                                            KickIra.basketballContent()
                                    }

Comment: remove all static world and instead of  `KickIra.basketballContent() use this.basketballContent()` replace `KickIra` by `this`.

Comment: thank you so much it worked, can you tell why it worked after removing static, since in future I wontmake that mistake...

Comment: check the link pasted in ans, if you use static then a static method won't be able to access `this`, so you should avoid using static methods :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `if` statement in your JSX, learn how to do conditional rendering here: http://reactjs.cn/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

Comment: thanks for your reply...but if I am using ternary operator, I am facing this issue, can you help with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358231/onclick-function-not-working-for-anchor-tag?noredirect=1#comment71867709_42358231

Comment: don't use a ternary operator, use something like this: http://doora.qiniudn.com/IDWMf.png

Comment: any idea about this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358231/onclick-function-not-working-for-anchor-tag?noredirect=1#comment71867709_42358231

Comment: that's not relative with this question

Answer (score 0):

You can code for condition using ternary operator.
In your case,

```
 {
  this.props.playerInfo.fundingDetailId === null) ? 
   <div>
    <a className="closeButton" onclick={this.hidePopover}>Close</a>
    <a className="iraRollover usaa-modal-trigger" href="javascript:;" 
        onClick={this.openIRATracker}>
    Check Out IRA Rollover Tracker
    </a>
   </div>
: 'here else part'
}
```

And for anchor tag onClick method issue.
Either do this way,

```
onClick={() => {this.setState({var:'value'}) }}
```

Or
Bind the method in constructor. Like

```
this.method = this.method.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own IF component to use in JSX:

Definition

```
import React from 'react';

export class IF extends React.Component {

    render(){
        let lookFor = this.props.condition ? THEN : ELSE;
        let children = this.props.children;
        if(Array.isArray(children)){
            children = children.filter((child) => child.type === lookFor)
        } else if(children.type !== lookFor){
            children = null;
        }
        return children;
    }
}

export class THEN extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return this.props.children;
    }
}

export class ELSE extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return this.props.children || null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
render(){ return (
<div>
  doSomething

  <IF condition={this.state.something === true}>
    <THEN>
      <div> is shown only if condition equals true </div>
    </THEN>
    <ELSE>
      <div> is shown only if condition equals false. ELSE can be omitted.
    </ELSE>
  </IF>

  doMore
</div>
);}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JSX you can use:

```
<div>
  {(() => {
    if(this.something){
      return <span>something</span>
    } else {
      return "nothing to see here";
  })()}
</div>
```

Or if you don't need "this" keyword.

```
<div>
  {function() {
    if(something){
      return <span>something</span>
    } else {
      return "nothing to see here";
  }()}
</div>
```